# Extracting hair color from JSON array

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am stuck with a small problem of extracting the first color of the persons hair from JSON data. I am very new to this and am having little success with it. Please help

Any ideas as to how I can get the color  of the hair out and setting it to a string?

```
[{"faceId":"b5472f5d-f6f2-41bd-9c52-cb585372108c","faceRectangle":{"top":1005,"left":786,"width":864,"height":864},"faceAttributes":{"smile":0.185,"headPose":{"pitch":0.0,"roll":-7.6,"yaw":9.2},"gender":"male","age":41.8,"facialHair":{"moustache":0.8,"beard":1.0,"sideburns":0.9},"glasses":"NoGlasses","emotion":{"anger":0.004,"contempt":0.012,"disgust":0.006,"fear":0.057,"happiness":0.185,"neutral":0.516,"sadness":0.043,"surprise":0.177},"blur":{"blurLevel":"medium","value":0.32},"exposure":{"exposureLevel":"goodExposure","value":0.6},"noise":{"noiseLevel":"high","value":1.0},"makeup":{"eyeMakeup":false,"lipMakeup":false},"accessories":[],"occlusion":{"foreheadOccluded":false,"eyeOccluded":false,"mouthOccluded":false},"hair":{"bald":0.05,"invisible":false,"hairColor":[{"color":"black","confidence":0.97},{"color":"brown","confidence":0.89},{"color":"other","confidence":0.41},{"color":"gray","confidence":0.22},{"color":"blond","confidence":0.17},{"color":"red","confidence":0.09}]}}}]
```

This is how I am trying to access the color but to no avail

```
string x = myObj.faceAttributes.hair.hairColor.ToString();
```

This is what I get back:

```
Debug Result: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.Model.HairColor]
```

Here are the classes:

```
  public class FaceRectangle
    {
        public int top { get; set; }
        public int left { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class HeadPose
    {
        public double pitch { get; set; }
        public double roll { get; set; }
        public double yaw { get; set; }
    }

    public class FacialHair
    {
        public double moustache { get; set; }
        public double beard { get; set; }
        public double sideburns { get; set; }
    }

    public class Emotion
    {
        public double anger { get; set; }
        public double contempt { get; set; }
        public double disgust { get; set; }
        public double fear { get; set; }
        public double happiness { get; set; }
        public double neutral { get; set; }
        public double sadness { get; set; }
        public double surprise { get; set; }
    }

    public class Blur
    {
        public string blurLevel { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Exposure
    {
        public string exposureLevel { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Noise
    {
        public string noiseLevel { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Makeup
    {
        public bool eyeMakeup { get; set; }
        public bool lipMakeup { get; set; }
    }

    public class Occlusion
    {
        public bool foreheadOccluded { get; set; }
        public bool eyeOccluded { get; set; }
        public bool mouthOccluded { get; set; }
    }

    public class HairColor
    {
        public string color { get; set; }
        public double confidence { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hair
    {
        public double bald { get; set; }
        public bool invisible { get; set; }
        public List<HairColor> hairColor { get; set; }
    }

    public class FaceAttributes
    {
        public double smile { get; set; }
        public HeadPose headPose { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public double age { get; set; }
        public FacialHair facialHair { get; set; }
        public string glasses { get; set; }
        public Emotion emotion { get; set; }
        public Blur blur { get; set; }
        public Exposure exposure { get; set; }
        public Noise noise { get; set; }
        public Makeup makeup { get; set; }
        public List<object> accessories { get; set; }
        public Occlusion occlusion { get; set; }
        public Hair hair { get; set; }
    }


    public class Face
    {
        public string faceId { get; set; }
        public FaceRectangle faceRectangle { get; set; }
        public FaceAttributes faceAttributes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hairColor is an array, so you have to specify which element you want.

```
string x = myObj.faceAttributes.hair.hairColor[0].color;
```

Comment: please Accept the answer (green check mark) if you found it helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the class structure, you will see that Hair contains a List of Hair Colour. The debug message is also telling you the same thing; that you are calling ToString() on a List.

Instead the correct approach would be to print out each of the Hair colours, either separately or as a comma separated value. Without knowing exactly how you want to output/use the hair colour(s) try one of the approaches below.

**Comma Separated:** This will produce a string of comma separated hair colours

```
string x = string.Join(",", myObj.faceAttributes.hair.hairColor);
```

**For Each:**

```
foreach (string x in myObj.faceAttributes.hair.hairColor)
{
    System.Out.WriteLine(x);
    // Or whatever else you would like to do with this.
}
```